# Integrate Payment API with wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How difficult is integrate Payment API with wordpress site?

Im trying to figure out how to integrate Montonio payment api with wordpress.

maybe possible add with hook?

Comment: Maybe install the wordpress plugin(Montonio) first and configure it from the backend.

Comment: you can create custom plugin and check this document from Montonio API document https://public.montonio.com/assets/libraries/MontonioAPI.php.txt for your reference

Comment: @ValentinMatzke not woocommerce site. I have wordpress. Montonio plugin is for woocommerce

Comment: Its not as simple as adding a hook. It will require knowledge of php, and a basic understanding of how the API functions as well as basic knowledge of how WordPress functions under the hood.

Comment: I'm adding with short code and process is done in subdomain.